# UserInterfaceStyle Light is not working for release builds

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, ios-darkmode

I force my application to be in Light mode by setting `User Interface Style = Light` in `plist` file.

However, it seems only works when i run app in debug mode (plug the cable and run). When i archive ipa and distribute to TestFlight, it doesnt work. 
Anyone has the same issues?

Note that status bar, actionsheet, alertview are affected controls.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Same issue facing, i have added it in plist as well as set to window, but some time it not working. Means when u update app that time it specially not worked. Also finding solution for this. There some issue at iOS side

Comment: Exactly what 's happening to me. Please give me updated if you find out somethings, @PravinTate

Answer (score 1):

You need to set this in `Appdelegate`. I am using this in all my apps and it's working.

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
}
```

For iOS 13 and above add this  in SceneDelegate.

```
 @available(iOS 13.0, *)
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
}
```

Comment: I did the same thing, it only works for debug mode, doesnt work when you build release.

Comment: remove it from plist and write this line down in Appdelegate only. My app is on testflight and even I uploaded my one app on Appstore and it's working quite right.

Comment: Also one more thing before installing release build uninstall the the first build you have in you device because I don't know if this is Xcode issue or what if you make changes it doesn't reflect in you app until you uninstall and install it.

Comment: Thanks, i removed the key from plist and only set `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` in `AppDelegate`  but the same problem.

Comment: @jacob have you found any solution? I am facing the same probelm

Comment: @iDeveloper: My problem is that i forgot to modify the plist info for Release Target. Please double check it in your side.

Comment: @iDeveloper check my updated answer I hope it will solve your issue.